# Deploy create-react-app on Azure App services

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, react-router, azure-web-app-service

I am new to React and created a simple react app using create-react-app , it builds and runs fine on local. I created a Azure Build and release pipelines and tried deploying using App Services , refereed below Microsoft link to implement the same.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/deploying-react-apps-to-azure-with-azure-devops/

Build and release pipeline runs successfully however when I click the Azure app services link to access the react app, I receive below message :-(

**"This react-naturalone.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found

No web page was found for the web address: https://react-naturalone.azurewebsites.net/

HTTP ERROR 404"**

Can someone please suggest what I am missing.

fyi, I am using react-router, hence added the web.config as mentioned in the link above.

Thanks
AOU

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that there is a problem with your deployment pipeline. The first step for your here is to go to your Azure portal and open up your app service. From your app service, go to -->Development tools --> App service editor.

Do you see your code inside it? If you don't, you can confirm that the code didn't deploy correctly. If you do, then you have a misconfiguration somewhere in your app that is preventing anybody from seeing it.

Comment: Thank you Jibreel, within the App service editor it has a link as "Go", when I click on it, it navigated to my app service Editor which has 3.zip and 4.zip when I download both have my source codes. There is also hosting.html and web.config .When you say misconfiguration, could you please point me in the right direction as where to look at. Many thanks

Comment: You should see a folder called "wwwroot" inside your app service folder. Inside wwwroot, you should have generally a home page like "index.html", a "web.config". What happens if you copy and paste these files in there from the app service editor, do you see something there???

From what you are saying, I think there is a problem with your deployment. You said your code is in a .zip but Azure usually unzips your files after deploy is complete. There must be something else wrong. Are you deploying a build of your code or just your code as is? You need to build it first.

Comment: Building code to run it from your ide or console is not the same as building it for deployment. Building it for deployment create a special version of it to use in another folder.

You should run a build command like `npm run build-css && react-scripts build` (depends on what libraries you have installed) and deploy *the build output*, not your actual code. Please try deploying the build of your code. 

If that works, please don't forget to select my comment as the selected answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you Jibreel.  Within the App Service Editor,  I have the following structure:                               
 `Working Files -> WWWROOT --> 3.zip  , 4.zip , hostingstart.html , web.config` , Sorry you asked me to copy  .html and .config but where do I paste them ? I have `npm build`   in my local it has created a compressed build folder however, when I push my code to Azure repo, the build folder is ignored. I have created a Build pipeline with Node.js, Npm Install,Publish artifcat drop. The Build pipeline created the artifacts which release pipelines uses to deploy to app services.

Comment: if the appropriate steps help in resolving the issue, will definitely select the answer :-) without fail

Comment: I browsed through the build artifacts on Azure DevOps, and the latest build has created 4.zip which is what I can see on App Service Editor.

Comment: Sorry I never followed up with you. Did you find the solution? Would you mind to share the fix if so?